Why is China not mentioned in the Fallout TV series despite its significant role in the games' lore?
In the 2024 Amazon Prime Video TV series Fallout, set in the same universe as the Fallout video games, I've noticed something interesting: there's a distinct lack of direct references to China's role in the nuclear apocalypse.
While dialogue in the TV series has alluded to "reds" and "commies" (indirectly referring to China), and there's been a reference to the USSR, China itself hasn't been explicitly mentioned as far as I can tell.
In the Fallout game series, the lore clearly establishes that the Great War—the nuclear apocalypse that set the stage for the entire narrative—was primarily a conflict between the United States and China. Some in-game elements even suggest that China might have initiated the nuclear exchange.
The absence of any reference to China in the TV series feels odd, especially considering how the games don’t shy away from portraying US-China hostilities. For example, in the Operation: Anchorage DLC for Fallout 3, the player character actually fights against Chinese troops. Fallout: New Vegas features a location called Little Yangtze, another clear nod to the US-China conflict. According to the "China" article on Nukapedia, China has been mentioned in all Fallout games so far.
Did the TV series creators or Amazon deliberately avoid mentioning China due to potential political or financial concerns? The Chinese government can be sensitive when it comes to depictions that cast China or its governance in an unfavorable light. Could this be the underlying reason behind the lack of explicit references to China in the series?
Why is China not mentioned in the Fallout TV series despite its significant role in the games' lore?

I think it's a reasonable question, but "distribution in China is very profitable" probably is the answer.

@FuzzyBoots Isn't Prime Video blocked in China?

@Raj That doesn't mean it can't be distributed at a later date, or via a different modality.

@FuzzyBoots it would make sense, after all it's what happened to the 2012 remake of "Red Dawn". Not that the changes made any logical sense, or made that terrible movie worth watching.

I recently replayed all of Fallout 3 and New Vegas - China is only explicitly referenced once, and it's in the virtual simulation of a full Chinese invasion. In the Mojave, which is closer to where the game takes place, there's almost no reference to them at all.

@Zibbobz It's been a while since I played, but I remember China coming up quite a bit in the lore. Terminal entries and in-game notes often mentioned China when discussing the Great War. A quick Google search for "terminal" and "China" on Nukapedia shows several references across various Fallout games.

@Zibbobz There is the Yangtze Memorial right outside of Goodsprings

@Jan I think I know what you're talking about, but I don't think I ever had any reason to go there, so I didn't.

@Zibbobz According to the "China" article on Nukapedia, China has been mentioned in all Fallout games so far.

As far as I know, there is no official commentary on why China is omitted. As I noted in the comments, China is sometimes avoided as a villain because they only allow a certain number of foreign films each year to be available in their potentially lucrative market, so casting China as a villain is seen as a potential revenue reducer either for an initial release, or in the physical media release.
However, this article mentions a more intriguing possibility, that mention of China was omitted to focus on the real enemy, Capitalism.

Over the past decade, political rhetoric against China has become totalizing, and the 2024 U.S. presidential election is poised to become a competition of which candidate will be “tougher on China.” Commentators have long noted that the U.S. discourse on China is unproductive, can limit diplomatic options for de-escalation, and may contribute to anti-Asian racism. Yet both Democrats and Republicans, especially in battleground states, continue to frame beating China as a central tenet of their foreign-policy agendas.
If both U.S. President Joe Biden’s and former President Donald Trump’s campaign rhetoric are to be taken at face value, Americans should theoretically be primed for a story that implicates China in the downfall of American well-being.
Instead, Fallout’s choice of villain may be tapping into an uncomfortable truth: Americans appear to be far less anxious about threats coming from beyond our borders than governance failures at home.

....

By choosing Vault-Tec, a rapacious corporation feasting on defense contracts, as the show’s true antagonist—particularly while public perceptions of corporations are at historic lows—Fallout offers an acute reading of the current political moment. The series’ latest installation makes clear that the end of the world, in all its bizarre humor, is a product of the worst aspects of ourselves, not from some malevolent anti-American force. Even China, as an equal participant in the nuclear exchange that underwrites the entire premise of Fallout, is ultimately a distraction from the true horseman of the apocalypse: a private, unregulated capitalist body with every appalling feature of present-day American corporations rolled into one.


Wasn't Vault-Tec the main antagonist from the beginning in the games, though? I don't know if it was implied that they contributed to the nuclear apocalypse, but the whole premise is about their bizarre human experimentation on people in fallout shelters. Not to mention that the USSR, USA and China are all basically non-existent as such during the time period during which most of the series takes place, so having any of those governments as the antagonists would be unusual.

“mention of China was omitted to focus on the real enemy, Capitalism” Jeff Bezos is like, “Hey, don’t look at me!”

@galacticninja Those Che Guevara shirts aren't going to sell themselves...

@Adamant It's Vault-Tec that didn't exist any more. Remnants of USA are the Enclave. Vault-Tec in the TV series is pretty much a cheap Enclave knock-off.

@Mithoron - Yes, but their vaults are still very much present and threatening.

@Adamant IIRC at the first two games there was nothing "fishy" about Vault-Tec. It was only from Fallout 3 that the vaults being anything other than shelters was revealed. And it was a thing of the past, Vault-Tec no longer existing (other than in the form of the ghoul of the sales rep at Fallout 4). On top of that, while the experiments were sadistic to the point of being dumb (or comical), it did not appear that Vault-Tec had any power outside of their vaults.

@SJuan76 not so in the TV show, though. There are frequent flashbacks to events leading up to the war showing the involvement of VaultTec. The backstory and initial world-view of the protagonist are heavily influenced by VaultTec corporate propaganda. And without spoiling too much of the TV show, many of the central conflicts are indeed caused by people who were associated with VaultTec before the war.

Flamewar initiator: Have you noticed that the most capitalistic economy is the chinese one?

@galacticninja It's "the heart of Wal*mart" from South Park...

While the comments in Fuzzyboot's answer shed some light on this, it is also highly likely that they steered clear of any negative mentions of China because China tends to block the release of anything seen as painting China in a negative light. An unrelated movie, Sight, was not allowed to release in China because of some of the depictions of the Communist revolution

Angel Studios has a new film coming out in theaters on Friday, but the Chinese Communist Party is refusing to let it be shown to viewers in China. Angel Studios' Jared Geesey told The Post Millennial that distributors "can't touch" the film because of its discussion of the Chinese Cultural Revolution.
"This film is resonating with the Chinese, but the Chinese distributors tell us that they can’t touch any film addressing the cultural revolution," Geesey said.

As Amazon makes the Fallout series, the company likely did not want its broader offerings impacted by Chinese censors. Amazon has done similar things in the past

A Chinese company that operates Amazon’s cloud-computing and online services business there said on Tuesday that it told local customers to cease using any software that would allow Chinese to circumvent the country’s extensive system of internet blocks.

And

The move came at roughly the same time that Apple said it took down a number of apps from its China app store that help users vault the Great Firewall. Those apps helped users connect to the rest of the internet world using technology called virtual private networks, or VPNs.
Taken together, the recent moves by Apple and Amazon show how Beijing is increasingly forcing America’s biggest tech companies to play by Chinese rules if they want to maintain access to the market. The push comes even as the number of foreign American tech companies able to operate and compete in China has dwindled.


On the TV show, the society depicted in the show is somewhat a resemblance of 50s society but with some distopic twist that can make us think this is not our temporal line.
Anyone paying attention to modern politics can see the evolution of China as a future (almost-present) super power antagonic to US, but back on 50s those role was fullfilled by the USSR.
If you don't want to scare a potentially very profitable market, as chinese, depicting them as the baddies, you could perfectly add this retro ambience to your pre-war scripting, looking to make reasonable to see USSR as the antagonist instead of China.

They are supposed to be in continuity. If it worked out all that perfectly is another matter.

@Mithoron TV show's pre-war ambience doesn't seem like 2077 to me ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Also, my answer is perfectly compatible with other answers that seems this as something made for economic purposes, I just add it a script reasoning

Sorry, but it's simple incorrect. They year the war started is mentioned in the TV and the same as in games. They both take place in alternate history that diverged just after II World War. Pre-apocalypse society in the games was supposed to resemble 50s society but with some distopic twist.

@Mithoron didn't recall that... changed the answer to ignore date of events, just reinforce the idea of a cultural shifting to 50s ambience, when URSS was the super power that fullfilled the role of a nuclear antagonist.

Yeah, I agree. The show and the games are big on 50s anti-nostalgia/snark.  The show goes more explicitly into McCarthyism with the Hollywood blackballing.  Anyone coming from the games knows it's China.  Anyone coming into the show knows it's McCarthy.  Brilliant and you don't need to call out China, but it's always there if you want to think about it.  Add a suitable, higher-grade mode of anti-Capitalism with an even more explicit callout of Vaultec and almost everyone in the various audience demographic groups is happy.

I expected USSR, yet this answer uses  URSS. LSNED,

@chux-ReinstateMonica fixed. Misspell from spanish, which is my mother language, where it's spelled URSS instead of USSR

A couple of thoughts, in addition to the points about possible censorship in China and chosing a more relatable enemy.
First and foremost, as you mention, China belongs to the lore of the series. Narration at the start, notes found in computers. IIRC correctly maybe there are three or four encounters with Chinese forces in the series, and those are either simulations or small remants of infiltration teams. They are never a faction to deal with seriously.
In other words, China makes for a good filler if you are spending lots of time in a videogame, to inmerse yourself in the environment. But it makes for an awful lot of unneeded exposition for a film or tv show that needs to be fast paced. You may have a TV series about vikings, but you will not have a TV series about a classroom where the teacher explains the history of the vikings(*1).
Additionally, maybe the international changes make mentioning China less appealing. Remember, those games are old. And they depict a very unpleasant story of nuclear war destroying civilization(*2).
So, perhaps China was chosen because it was not seen as very threatening to the USA, to the point that you could enjoy a videogame in which China had destroyed the USA because it was unrealistic. Nowadays, it is not that a global thermonuclear war seems near, but tensions with China are certainly higher and its perceived military power, greater. Which could lead to the series direction chosing to not to emphasize this angle.
(*1) To put another examples, the "Planet of the Apes" book has a part explaining how the apes got to replace the humans. But, in the films set at a time frame where the apes control the planet, that exposition is never done.
(*2) Bongo, bongo, bongo.
